# Is there any way to get current Heroku Dyno memeory usage of Rails App?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, memory, dyno

I am running the **large Rails App** which consumes much memory on **Heroku**.

I would like to know the current **Heroku Dyno memory usage** regularly.

I have checked this [script](https://gist.github.com/ssimeonov/6027269) but not sure how I can use this script.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/log-runtime-metrics is your best bet for monitoring dyno memory usage. Then hook it up to a https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/librato addon.

Comment: No, this is not helpful to check memory in the code.

Comment: Okay, maybe I should have started by asking, _why_ do you want to monitor memory usage in the app? monitoring should always be done from outside the app, because it's not the responsibility of the app logic to do this. What do you plan on doing with this information in the app?

Comment: I am going to check the memory usage of the dyno regularly and if it consumes much memory to hit Heroku R14 error, then I am going to restart dyno. I am going to do all these steps by code, not manually.